# how to crop a return value of a command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

please consider this command taked to the command prompt:

pfm flush v:\nuova\a1.avs

[image]

he returns:

**c:\volumes\a1.avs**

I'm already in a batch processing, but I need to get c:\volumes\a1.avs in a variable (e.g. called %vol%)

How can I crop this value ("c:\volumes\a1.avs")?

thanks

Comment: so that: in this case I get %vol% = c:\volumes\a1.avs

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('pfm flush v:\nuova\a1.avs') do set "vol=%%a"
```

would be the standard response.

but in this case, now I've seen the actual output,

```
for /f "tokens=1delims= " %%a in ('pfm flush v:\nuova\a1.avs') do set "vol=%%~a"
```

because the quoted item would be token 1 and the separator is a space (hence the space between `=` and `"` after `delims`.

The `~` removes the quotes.

Comment: Consider `for /f delims^=^" %%a ...` if returned path could contain space(s).

Comment: @Josefz: Did you actually try the code with a path containing spaces?

Comment: `for /f delims^=^" %a in ('echo "a x y" flush') do @echo [%a]` returns `[a x y]`. I don't know whether `pfm` _could_ return path with spaces...

Comment: @JosefZ: So your point is that your version of the code works - is that what you are saying? Did you try the version I posted? OK - I've assumed (for lack of further information) that OP is executing this command as part of a batch file, not from the prompt. So - reduce `%%` to `%` to execute from the prompt, and perhaps change the variable-name since `vol` is a command.

Comment: I'm trying to say: I do not know `pfm` and _what-if_ it _could_ return `"c:\my volumes\a1.avs"` instead of `"c:\volumes\a1.avs"`? Then, `for /f delims^=^"  %%a in ('pfm flush v:\nuova\a1.avs') do set "vol=%%a"` would become useful.

Comment: for /f delims^=^" %%a in ('pfm flush "%~dp1%~n1_HDavs.avs"') do set "flushed=%%a"                 seems work ok!!! THANKS THANKS